# How to get a proper invoice from meetup.com

Tags: meetup

I manage a meetup which is paid for by my employer. My employer needs an invoice that conforms to German tax legislation, so the recipient must contain our full company name, address and VAT number.

But the invoice sent to me contains the card holder data of our credit card, which unfortunately does not contain our full company name, and includes my personal email address which should be omitted there.

Meetup support told me the only way to change the recipient data is to cancel and resubscribe using a payment method that contains our company data, and that they, as a U.S. based company working with a third party (Stripe) do not provide invoices at all, all they do provide are receipts.

As there are many meetup groups and quite a lot of them seem to be sponsored by companies, I am probably not the first one with this problem. So I would like to hear about possible solutions someone found already.

Comment: Not a real answer, but don't rely on meetup! More and more user groups move back to using their own websites and mailing lists, and cross-post on LinkedIn, to prevent vendor lock-in to meetup's services. Another reason: meetup threatens to delete all of your group content once you stop paying their subscription. So in the end, we should stop using meetup.com at all.